# CMake - How to avoid CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in linker command-line

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, g++, linker-flags

I'm having a problem with cmake / gcc / Linux.

No matter what I try, I cannot get rid of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS on my linker line. CMake keeps passing them when invoking g++ in link mode.

I have -fopenmp in my CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and it must not be present on the link line so g++ doesn't link to gomp (I'm using Intel's iomp5 instead).

Edit: I tried the following the beginning of CMakeLists.txt, didn't help:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER>  <FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

Thanks

Comment: Redefining `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` should help. Show what have you tried (in form of [mcve]). Also, as suggested [in that answer] for similar question, you may use `COMPILE_FLAGS` **property** for compiler-only options.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out

```
add_compile_options("-fopenmp")
```

avoids adding these options to the linker.
It doesn't solve the general issue of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS showing up in the linker line, but it solves the immediate problem I have.